# OSX terminal stopped working?

Tags: macos, terminal

For some reason, many command I try to execute I get `command not found`
I've tried `touch, mkdir, sudo, ln -s` all the same result

```
ilyas-mac-pro:~ ilya$ mkdir bla
-bash: mkdir: command not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You changed your `$PATH` ([more about it](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables/284351#284351)). Try to enter the full path of commands, e.g. `/bin/mkdir` (or `/usr/bin/mkdir`, not sure right now).

`echo $PATH` to see the current path variable value.

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin` for a sane value.

Check your shell init files, e.g. `.profile` or `.bash_profile` for lines like the `export PATH=...` above and remove them.

Comment: To add to Daniel's answer, the proper default for $PATH in OSX is /usr/bin

Comment: @Yitzchak: The default PATH on OS X 10.6 is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`.  It should *always* include at least `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` since the "standard" system binaries are spread between those 4 directories.

Comment: I stand corrected. I haven't used OSX since leopard.